# line : 154 "target1_object.value" what is the value its using how it work

Tags: pine-script

the below code is from tradingview and it is pinescript on line 154 "target1_object.value"is where i have problem i cant understand where that one is getting value from and how its working. apart from that rest are good for me

what is "target1_object.value"?

where is getting value from?

```
// This work is licensed under a Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International (CC BY-NC-SA 4.0) https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/
// © LuxAlgo

//@version=5
indicator("Targets For Overlay Indicators [LuxAlgo]", shorttitle = "LuxAlgo - Targets For Overlay Indicators", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500, max_labels_count = 500)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Target 1
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
source = input.source(close)
showLabels = input(true, 'Show Target Labels')
candleColoring = input(true, 'Candle Coloring')

//Crossover Target
enableTarget1 = input(true, 'Show Crossover Target'
  , group     = 'Crossover Source')

isLong1       = input(true, 'Above Price Target'
  , inline    = 'enable'
  , group     = 'Crossover Source')

//Target 1 Logic
waitTarget1   = input(false, 'Wait Until Reached'
  , group     = 'Crossover Source')

newTarget1    = input(false, 'New Target When Reached'
  , group     = 'Crossover Source')

useWicks1     = input(true, 'Evaluate Wicks'
  , group     = 'Crossover Source')

distTarget1   = input.float(3, 'Target Distance From Price'
  , inline    = 'dist1'
  , group     = 'Crossover Source')

distOptions1  = input.string('ATR', ''
  , options   = ['Currencies', '%', 'ATR', 'Ticks']
  , inline    = 'dist1'
  , group     = 'Crossover Source')

target1Css    = input(#089981, 'Target Color '
  , inline    = 'style'
  , group     = 'Crossover Source')

target1Style  = input.string('- - -', '    Levels Style'
  , options   = ['──','- - -','· · ·']
  , inline    = 'style'
  , group     = 'Crossover Source')

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Target 2
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Crossunder Target
enableTarget2 = input(true, 'Show Crossunder Target'
  , group     = 'Crossunder Source')

isLong2       = input(false, 'Above Price Target'
  , inline    = 'enable'
  , group     = 'Crossunder Source')

//Target 1 Logic
waitTarget2   = input(false, 'Wait Until Reached'
  , group     = 'Crossunder Source')

newTarget2    = input(false, 'New Target When Reached'
  , group     = 'Crossunder Source')

useWicks2     = input(true, 'Evaluate Wicks'
  , group     = 'Crossunder Source')

distTarget2   = input.float(3, 'Target Distance From Price'
  , inline    = 'dist1'
  , group     = 'Crossunder Source')

distOptions2  = input.string('ATR', ''
  , options   = ['Currencies', '%', 'ATR', 'Ticks']
  , inline    = 'dist1'
  , group     = 'Crossunder Source')

target2Css    = input(#f23645, 'Target Color '
  , inline    = 'style'
  , group     = 'Crossunder Source')

target2Style  = input.string('- - -', '    Levels Style'
  , options   = ['──','- - -','· · ·']
  , inline    = 'style'
  , group     = 'Crossunder Source')

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Dashboard
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
showDash      = input.bool     (    true      , 'Show Dashboard'                                                     , group = 'Dashboard')
dashLoc       = input.string   (  'Top Right' , 'Location'  , options = ['Top Right', 'Bottom Right', 'Bottom Left'] , group = 'Dashboard')
textSize      = input.string   (   'Normal'   , 'Size'      , options =          ['Tiny', 'Small', 'Normal']         , group = 'Dashboard')

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//UDT
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
type lshape
    line v
    line h

type target
    float  value
    int    loc
    bool   reached
    bool   islong
    bool   active
    lshape lines
    label  lbl

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Functions
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
n = bar_index

method set_target(target id, css, lstyle)=>
    style = switch lstyle
        '- - -' => line.style_dashed
        '· · ·' => line.style_dotted
        =>         line.style_solid
    
    id.lines := lshape.new(line.new(n, close, n, id.value, color = css, style = style),
      line.new(n, id.value, n, id.value, color = css, style = style))

method delete(target id)=>
    id.lines.v.delete()
    id.lines.h.delete()

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Set crossover target
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var color css            = na
bool      isNewTarget1   = false
bool      isTgReached1   = false

var int countTargets1   = 0
var int countTgReached1 = 0

var target1_object      = target.new(reached = true, active = false)

target1_condition = ta.crossover(close, source)

//Distance
dist1 = switch distOptions1
    'Currencies' => distTarget1
    '%' => close + distTarget1 / 100 * close
    'ATR' => nz(ta.atr(50)) * distTarget1
    'Ticks' => syminfo.mintick * distTarget1

if target1_object.active and target1_object.reached == false
    target1_object.lines.h.set_x2(n)
    target1_object.lbl.set_x(n)

if (isLong1 ? (useWicks1 ? high : close) > target1_object.value : (useWicks1 ? low : close) < target1_object.value) and target1_object.active 
    target1_object.reached := true
    target1_object.active  := false 
    isTgReached1           := true
    countTgReached1        += 1
    css := na
    target1_object.lbl.set_color(target1Css)

if enableTarget1 and 
 (
  (target1_condition and (waitTarget1 ? target1_object.reached : true)) 
  or 
  (newTarget1 and target1_object.reached)
 ) 
    target_value = close + (isLong1 ? dist1 : -dist1)

    //Delete label if reached and creating new target
    if newTarget1 and target1_object.reached and showLabels
        target1_object.lbl.delete()

    //Create new target
    target1_object := target.new(target_value, n, false, isLong1, active = true)

    if showLabels
        target1_object.lbl := label.new(n, target_value, 'Target'
          , color = color.new(target1Css, 50)
          , textcolor = color.white
          , size = size.tiny
          , style = label.style_label_left
          , tooltip = str.tostring(target_value, format.mintick))

    css := target1Css

    target1_object.set_target(target1Css, target1Style)

    isNewTarget1  := true 
    countTargets1 += 1

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Set crossunder target
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
bool isNewTarget2   = false
bool isTgReached2   = false

var int countTargets2   = 0
var int countTgReached2 = 0

var target2_object = target.new(reached = true, active = false)

target2_condition = ta.crossunder(close, source)

//Distance
dist2 = switch distOptions2
    'Currencies' => distTarget2
    '%' => close + distTarget2 / 100 * close
    'ATR' => nz(ta.atr(50)) * distTarget2
    'Ticks' => syminfo.mintick * distTarget2

if target2_object.active and target2_object.reached == false
    target2_object.lines.h.set_x2(n)
    target2_object.lbl.set_x(n)

if (isLong2 ? (useWicks2 ? high : close) > target2_object.value : (useWicks2 ? low : close) < target2_object.value) and target2_object.active 
    target2_object.reached := true
    target2_object.active  := false 
    isTgReached2           := true
    countTgReached2        += 1
    css := na
    target2_object.lbl.set_color(target2Css)

if enableTarget2     and
 (
  (target2_condition and (waitTarget2 ? target2_object.reached : true)) 
  or 
  (newTarget2 and target2_object.reached)
 ) 
    target_value = close + (isLong2 ? dist2 : -dist2)

    //Delete label if reached and creating new target
    if newTarget2 and target2_object.reached and showLabels
        target1_object.lbl.delete()

    //Create new target
    target2_object := target.new(target_value, n, false, isLong2, active = true)

    if showLabels
        target2_object.lbl := label.new(n, target_value, 'Target'
          , color = color.new(target2Css, 50)
          , textcolor = color.white
          , size = size.tiny
          , style = label.style_label_left
          , tooltip = str.tostring(target_value, format.mintick))
    
    css := target2Css

    target2_object.set_target(target2Css, target2Style)

    isNewTarget2  := true 
    countTargets2 += 1

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Plots
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
barcolor(candleColoring ? css : na, title = 'Candle Coloring')

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Dashboard
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var table_position = dashLoc == 'Bottom Left' ? position.bottom_left 
  : dashLoc == 'Top Right' ? position.top_right 
  : position.bottom_right

var table_size = textSize == 'Tiny' ? size.tiny 
  : textSize == 'Small' ? size.small 
  : size.normal

var tb = table.new(table_position, 3, 4
  , bgcolor      = #1e222d
  , border_color = #373a46
  , border_width = 1
  , frame_color  = #373a46
  , frame_width  = 1)

if showDash

    if barstate.isfirst
        if enableTarget1 or enableTarget2
            tb.cell(0, 0,             ''           , text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size)
            tb.cell(1, 0,          'Count'         , text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size)
            tb.cell(2, 0,    'Target\nReached'     , text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size)
            tb.cell(0, 3,         'Total'          , text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size)

        if enableTarget1
            tb.cell(0, 1,        'Target 1'        , text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size)
        if enableTarget2
            tb.cell(0, 2,        'Target 2'        , text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size)

    if barstate.islast
        totT = countTargets1   + countTargets2        
        totR = countTgReached1 + countTgReached2
 
        if totT == 0
            tb.clear(0, 0, 2, 3)
            tb.cell(0, 0, 'Please Select another input source from the "Source" setting.', text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size)
        else
            if enableTarget1
                tb.cell(1, 1, str.tostring(countTargets1)                                                                       , text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size)
                tb.cell(2, 1, str.format  ('{0} ({1}%)', countTgReached1 , math.round(100 / countTargets1 * countTgReached1, 1)), text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size)
            if enableTarget2
                tb.cell(1, 2, str.tostring(countTargets2)                                                                       , text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size)
                tb.cell(2, 2, str.format  ('{0} ({1}%)', countTgReached2 , math.round(100 / countTargets2 * countTgReached2, 1)), text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size)
            if enableTarget1 or enableTarget2
                tb.cell(1, 3, str.tostring(     totT    )                                                                       , text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size)
                tb.cell(2, 3, str.format  ('{0} ({1}%)',       totR      , math.round(100 /      totT     *       totR     , 1)), text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size)


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Alerts
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
alertcondition(isNewTarget1, "Target 1 New"    , "Target 1 New"    )
alertcondition(isTgReached1, 'Target 1 Reached', 'Target 1 Reached')

alertcondition(isNewTarget2, "Target 2 New"    , "Target 2 New"    )
alertcondition(isTgReached2, 'Target 2 Reached', 'Target 2 Reached')

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`target` is a user defined object.

```
type target
    float  value
    int    loc
    bool   reached
    bool   islong
    bool   active
    lshape lines
    label  lbl
```

The object you are questioning `target1_object` is declared at line #139.

```
var target1_object      = target.new(reached = true, active = false)
```

At this point, no `value` is assigned to it. That is done later in the code at line #175.

```
target1_object := target.new(target_value, n, false, isLong1, active = true)
```

Here the object is overwritten and with the `new()` function, `target_value` is assigned to its `value` field.

And the `target_value` is calculated at line #168 as below:

```
target_value = close + (isLong1 ? dist1 : -dist1)
```